# Besides cache, what does the Linux kernel use significant amounts of memory for?

Tags: linux-kernel, performance, ram

My computer feels really sluggish. According to `free`, I have only ~200M RAM left and more than a gigabyte had to be swapped out. I know that it is good if memory is used for caching but this looks like I'm genuinely low on RAM.

```
root@desktop:/proc free -h
               total       used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.9G        3.4G        132M         44M        378M        213M
Swap:          8.0G        1.2G        6.7G
```

`smem -tk` reports that at most 2GiB (RSS column) are used by applications. `smem -wk` accounts for all the memory that is used. Apparently the kernel uses 1.8GiB not for caching:

```
root@desktop:/proc smem -wk
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory          1.9G      74.3M       1.8G 
userspace memory               1.8G     250.9M       1.6G 
free memory                  173.9M     173.9M          0
```

Is this behaviour expected, and if yes, for what task does the kernel need so much memory?

Comment: Please post the output of `</proc/slabinfo awk '{print $1, $3*$4}' |sort -k2n` (that gives a first-level breakdown of kernel memory usage).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ehahn/102aaddf46f3995bb59e

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

Use *sar* to report on context-switches and irq use over time. Sar is a great but unhearalded system monitoring tool. Run it for a day and then use various reports to look for oddness.

Steps:

Install the sysstat package. Set up the cron job (check `/etc/cron.d/` to see if such a file exists) like this:

```
* * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -S XALL 10 6
```

*This will create lots of data* -- about 300 MB per day. It will take a snapshot of the system statistics *every 6 seconds*.  (You can decrease the frequency to twice per minute by changing "10 6" to "2 30")

If you change the capturing frequency, you should erase the day's file in `/var/log/sa/sa$(date +%d)` -- otherwise the reports might get corrupted.

OK, after you have captured your data, try these (Tip: always pipe through `less`):

```
sar -q
```

To get load-averages and the run-queue sizes. If these are low, then look at the IO wait times:

```
sar -P ALL
```

If you don't see jumps in %iowait or troughs in %idle, then check out context-switches:

```
saw -w
```

500 context-switches per second is pretty normal on a mostly-idle system.

You can limit sar reporting by specifying the activity file, giving a start- and end-time (`-s <hh:mm:ss>` and `-e <hh:mm:sss>` respectively) and optionally an interval time with `-i <secs>` (must be greater than your capturing resolution, set up by the cron job).

Example:

```
sar -f /var/log/sa/sa$(date +%d -d yesterday) -s 09:15:00 -e 12:15:00 -i 600
```

will give you summary info for the CPU in 10-minute intervals from yesterday between 9:15 and 12:15.

There's more... much more. You can do `man sar` to get that info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you edited the `free -h` output command which lacks the `-/+ buffers/cache` line - which is important. Anyway we can proceed.

As long as the 'Free' column (on the Mem: line) is >0, you're not really low on RAM as this is **absolutely unused RAM**. And Linux is well known to use all the RAM it can get (as caches, hoping for better perforamnce).

The swap part does not tell the whole truth : it's quite common to have lots of code+data swapped to disk because it was only run once and not used for a while. Another part where Linux shows it's greedy on RAM for performance : it swiftly kicks out what's probably unimportant (again, performance-wise). It's tunable (sysctl vm.swappiness), but most distro defaults to "do not hesitate to swap".

What's important to confirm your hypothesis (slow because lack of available RAM) is if it's currently swapping in or out to disk. Most of the time it's quite easy to correlate sluginess to a franticallyt blinking disk led on one's computer. Otherwise, run `top` and looks at swap figures evolution over time. Even easier, `vmstat 1` will directly print the swap IO figures every second (swap si/so).

Comment: There is no buffers/cache line. I've been wondering why myself. My `free ` comes from procps-ng 3.3.10.

Comment: It's unfair to just call Linux greedy for how it uses the swap: how quickly it swaps out depends on your swappiness setting, which is up to you. Try `sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and see the difference.

Comment: OK, but most of the time the default is "please swap ASAP" and there's rarely a reason to do otherwise (unless you're in that league where every ms of latency counts). I edited my comment to mention swappinness configurabiliy.